# Tomcat restarts even after explicit shutdown

Tags: service, ubuntu-16.04, systemctl, tomcat8

I needed to set up an Ubuntu server based Tomcat server and I followed [this well written post](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04). Everything works great. Ran into an odd behavior though; I needed to stop the Tomcat server, so I used the command:

```
sudo /opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh
```

However, in about 10 seconds, Tomcat automatically restarted. How is that happening? Does the following command:

```
sudo systemctl enable tomcat
```

automatically start the Tomcat service, if its status is periodically checked and found to be stopped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should start, restart, stop tomcat with systemd commands.
You have started tomcat service`sudo systemctl start tomcat`, so if you want to stop it you need to go trough systemd:`sudo systemctl stop tomcat`.
In the unit file, according to the link that you posted, are settings that are: 
`RestartSec=10` which instructs systemd to restart tomcat.service after 10 sec in the case of failure or exit, and `Restart=always` instructs systemd to do it restart tomcat.service always no mater what is the reason of failure or exit, except if it was due systemd action. There is good explanation [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#). So you are trying to shutdown tomcat beside systemd, and systemd sees that as some irregularity in tomcat.service behavior and restarts it.

This command:

```
sudo systemctl enable tomcat
```

tells systemd to start the tomcat.service on the system startup, and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks @dexter for pointing out my mistake and for the links. Total user error on my part!